# Как получить файл по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, java

На нужной мне странице есть такая ссылка, при нажатии на нее выдается запрос на сохранение файла. Можно ли как-то из java-кода получить этот файл?

Ссылка:

```
<a id="ctl00_BXContent_lbCSV"     href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$BXContent$lbCSV','')">CSV (разделители - точка с запятой)</a>
```

Код JavaScript:

```
<pre>
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];

if (!theForm) {

    theForm = document.aspnetForm;

}

function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {

    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {

        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;

        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;

        theForm.submit();

    }

}
</pre
```

Comment: @b1ack_ange1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

1. Получить html.
2. Выдернуть аргументы из `onclick`.
3. Собрать инпуты формы.
4. Проставить дополнительно `__EVENTTARGET` и `__EVENTARGUMENT`, воспользовавшись выдернутыми атрибутами.
5. Сформировать запрос и скачать ответ как файл.

Comment: Вот, для пример, что лежит в нужных инпутах, на странице есть еще около 5-6 инпутов, там есть не пустые значения. Как сформировать запрос?
1: input#__EVENTTARGET
.
.
.
value: ""
valueAsDate: null
valueAsNumber: NaN
.
.
.
2: input#__EVENTARGUMENT
.
.
.
value: ""
valueAsDate: null
valueAsNumber: NaN

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть здесь: http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-300487.html

Comment: @Ilja, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 0):

Решение в лоб: интерпретируйте javascript в вашем приложении.

Это универсально и отвечает вашим требованиям.